# Facelets SEO advice

Tags: internationalization, seo, googlebot

Before I deploy the new version of my site, I would like to know a little more about facelets and SEO.

My previous version of site was written in JSF and I noticed that when I submitted it to the google crawler, that the crawler did not locate all relevant sections of my site from my index page.

1)I presume this is because the crawler uses raw hyperlink anchors to navigate around the site and does not understand:
     h:outputlink ? 
If this is true, then Facelets is already an improvement as the developer can use raw anchors with the jsfc attribute.

2)What about Meta tags? Is there a way to get internationalization into a sites meta tags? I can only think that one has to write a tag for each language or not?

I am referring to the following two tags (as an example):

```
<meta name="description" content="thejarbar.org tutorial to set PATH variable" />
<meta name="keywords" content="thejarbar.org, tutorial, guide, instructions, example, howto, Java, PATH,
        setup, variable" />
```

3)Question 2 extends to the tooltip attributes and alt attributes for images. How do you optimize these for crawlers and internationalization?

Answer (score 3):

I think you're a bit confused between server side templates and the actual HTML that's generated from them.

h:ouputlink does *not* appear in the rendered output, so whether or not the crawler understands this is irrelevant.

Normally, h:ouputlink is rendered as a normal anchor (which crawlers can't distinguish from any anchor link that you manually put on your page).

So whatever your problem is with SEO, the cause is most likely not the one you think it is.

Comment: Fair enough, but the crawler is not a user. I have no way of knowing if

Comment: Sorry I understand that the crawler sees the same thing as I do if I view my source in browser, this leads me to believe that a meta tag is needed for each individual language supported with regards to SEO?